# Mixing type conversions and opaque types with pybind11

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am making use of opaque types with pybind11. For example, I defined one for the stl container `std::vector<uint32_t>`, which is a argument type of the method `FromVec`:

```cpp
void FromVec(std::vector<uint32_t> vec);

PYBIND11_MAKE_OPAQUE(std::vector<uint32_t>);

PYBIND11_MODULE(tmap, m)
{
    py::bind_vector<std::vector<uint32_t>>(m, "VectorUint", 
      "Unsigned 32-bit int vector.");

    m.def("from_vec", &FromVec, py::arg("vec")
}
```

With this I can now (in Python) do the following:

```py
vec = VectorUint([2, 66, 262, 662, 26, 62])
from_vec(vec)
```

However, type conversion does not work anymore, as the function now expects a `VectorUint` and doesn't accept `list` anymore, e.g.:

```py
l = [2, 66, 262, 662, 26, 62]
from_vec(l)
```

Is there a way to allow for both, oblique types and type conversion? That is, when a `list` is passed instead of a oblique bound `VectorUint` it is converted to a `std::vector<uint32_t>` rather than Python throwing "incompatible function arguments"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need automatic conversion to `std::vector` from `list` you can add such overload to your binding code:

```
m.def("from_vec", &FromVec, py::arg("vec")); // accepts VectorUnit 
m.def("from_vec", [](py::list& list){ /* do conversion manually and call FromVec */ } ); // accepts python list
```

Comment: It indeed looks like this is the (cumbersome) way to do it. Thanks. See associated issue: https://github.com/pybind/pybind11/issues/1940

Comment: Maybe as a short follow up: I'm currently trying to figure out how to best convert the py::list to a std::vector and the only way that I found working so far is looping over the list and adding the elements to a new vector. l.cast<std::vector<uint32_t>() would seem like the way to go, but this fails. So either this is by design or I'm messing up.

Answer (score 5):

Just add this after your `py::bind_vector`:

```
py::implicitly_convertible<py::list, std::vector<uint32_t>>();
```

It even works with properties (e.g. created with `def_readwrite`). You get the best of both worlds: The vector is accessed by reference from python, so that `append`, `extend`, etc work as expected; and you can assign from a python list (which will of course be copied).

EDIT: Unfortunately this trick doesn't work with `std::map` (don't know about other containers). As a workaround, you can use an intermediate map of a different type, e.g.:

```
namespace pybind11::workaround
{
  template<typename K, typename V>
  class Map : public std::map<K, V> {};
}

namespace pybind11::detail
{
  template<typename K, typename V>
  struct type_caster<workaround::Map<K, V>> : map_caster<workaround::Map<K, V>, K, V> {};
}

inline void bindCommonTypes(pybind11::handle scope)
{
  using IntMap = std::map<int, int>;
  py::bind_map<IntMap>(scope, "IntMap")
  .def(py::init([](const py::dict& dict) {
    return dict.cast<pybind11::workaround::Map<int, int>();
  }));
  py::implicitly_convertible<py::dict, IntMap>();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for putting into spotlight `py::implicitly_convertible` between opaque `std::vector` and `py::list`